# How do I run a simple 'hello world' program under QNX?

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, momentics

**Background**: I have the QNX license key and have installed the [VMWare target image](http://www.qnx.com/download/feature.html?programid=20725) from the QNX website into the VMWare. I have the QNX target RTOS running as a VM and my host machine has a QNX momentics IDE that can recognize the QNX target OS.

**Problem**: I have the license for the latest QNX SDP 7 and the [only VMWare compatible image I could find](http://www.qnx.com/download/feature.html?programid=20725) on the QNX website is an older QNX 6.5(?). A simple 'hello world' program (the demo program that ships with the Momentics IDE) will not run on the QNX target OS because it is missing certain libraries.

I need to either:

- Acquire the methodology to boot the latest version of QNX RTOS on VMWare. I have searched and searched in vain but this procedure is not described. The QNX SDP should have a way to create a bootable QNX RTOS for VMWare but the procedure is not listed anywhere (I have searched for days now!)

*OR*

- Find a way to use the Momentics IDE 7.0 with the older version of QNX RTOS that I have.

**Questions**:

- How do create a bootable QNX RTOS ISO and load it into VMWare using the QNX SDP 7.0?
- Make simple C/C++ programs created with QNX Momentics 7.0 run on the older version of QNX RTOS I have?

**Addendum**

[These are the instructions](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.qnxsdp.quickstart/topic/install_neutrino.html) they provide on how to acquire the latest QNX RTOS VMWare image. They say:

> We provide a VMware image that's compatible with VMware Workstation Pro 12.0 or later, VMware Workstation Player 12.0 or later, and VMware Fusion Pro 8.0 or later. This image is a minimal QNX Neutrino system. You can download a VMware image from the QNX Software Center by choosing the Available tab, expanding the Reference Images list, expanding the Tools list, and then choosing the appropriate virtual machine.

However, there's no 'reference images' or 'tools' or 'available tab' or anything like that in the software center (see images).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you open the QNX software center coming with QNX installation, and activate your license in that all the supported features which is available for you to download will be listed. in that the QNX VM image for v 7.0 is listed. you can download it directly from there.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instructions on how to download the QNX 7.0 VMWare image are located here: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.qnxsdp.quickstart/topic/install_neutrino.html

Historically, QNX build tools have been mostly forwards-compatible over minor version updates, but not backwards-compatible.   That is, I could compile a program with the QNX 6.5 SDK, and then run it on a 6.6 image; however a program compiled with the 6.6 SDK will not run on a 6.5 platform.  (The exceptions of course are programs that are loaded as shared objects into QNX applications, such as display or network drivers).  Major version updates (4.x to 6.x, 6.x to 7.x) are, to the best of my knowledge, not binary compatible at all.

Comment: Thank you but they do not have those VM images available in the software center. Please see my addendum in the original post above.

Comment: Confusingly, QNX seems to have two different "Software Center"s": the one on the web, in your screenshot above; and also an application called "Software Center" you can download -- you can see the links in your screenshot.  Try downloading the "Software Center" application and looking for the tab there?  Unfortunately I don't have a 7.0 license, so I can't post a screenshot from the application itself.